Missing bookmarks in generated document
I am having trouble with non-working hyperlinks in a document generated from Enterprise Architect. The hyperlinks, as usual, have expected structure with the prefix (#BKM_) and Ea_guid, but they do not link to any element in the document, despite the element being present as a header. Each hyperlink is composed correctly, but instead of linking to a specific place or reference in the document, they are not linking to anything.

To generate this output, I´m using the following template and fragment. This template searches the endpoints for a given connector and used the information of the source to populate the Fragment "Template A".

When using this template the bookmarks are created for the first Element.Name but not for the second one.
This problem seems to be related to the specific structure of the template. I am using a similar approach to populate other chapters of the document, and the bookmarks are created correctly. However, in this other structure, I do not use filters nor connectors in the template structure.

Instead, I feed the fragment directly with the target information. I have tried changing the header style, adding bookmarks in the element names, but none of these solutions have worked.
Has anyone else encountered this issue?

The element> inside a connector is not the same as the element> under a package. It's quite possible this only works for the latter.

Is it possible to get this confirmation sowhere? should I send email to sparx?

you can definitely try that yes. That's what support is for.
